# need help to fine tune query

Tags: c#, performance

HI i have this update query which works fine but just it takes about 3-4 seconds before i get the messagebox update successfully. Could you help to see what goes wrong? Is it because of the using() and the transaction rollback?

```
public void Update()
    {
        System.Data.Common.DbTransaction transaction = null;
        using (JamminDataContext db = new JamminDataContext())
        {
            try
            {
                db.Connection.Open();
                transaction = db.Connection.BeginTransaction();
                db.Transaction = transaction;

                #region Update Users
                db.Users.Attach(this, GetSingleUserById(this.Id));
                db.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, db.Users);
                db.SubmitChanges();
                #endregion

                if (this.RoleId == (int)RoleTypes.Student)
                {
                    #region Update CourseByStudents
                    foreach (CourseByStudent courseByStudent in this.courseByStudent)
                    {
                        if (courseByStudent == null) break;
                        if (courseByStudent.Id == 0)
                        {
                            courseByStudent.CourseUserStatus.UserId = this.Id;
                            db.CourseUserStatus.InsertOnSubmit(courseByStudent.CourseUserStatus);
                            db.SubmitChanges();

                            courseByStudent.StudentId = this.Id;
                            courseByStudent.CourseUserStatusId = courseByStudent.CourseUserStatus.Id;
                            db.CourseByStudents.InsertOnSubmit(courseByStudent);
                            db.SubmitChanges();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(courseByStudent.CourseUserStatusCopy != courseByStudent.CourseUserStatus.Status
                                && ( courseByStudent.CourseUserStatus.Status != null
                                && courseByStudent.CourseUserStatus.Date != null))
                            {
                                //Insert to CourseUserStatus only when Status is change or add new row of course
                                courseByStudent.CourseUserStatus.UserId = this.Id;
                                db.CourseUserStatus.InsertOnSubmit(courseByStudent.CourseUserStatus);
                                db.SubmitChanges();

                                courseByStudent.CourseUserStatusId = courseByStudent.CourseUserStatus.Id;
                            }
                            courseByStudent.Update();
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (transaction != null) transaction.Rollback();
                Logger.Error(typeof(User), ex);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (db.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) db.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: could this be done in a stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, but it is too late for me to even think of store procedure. I will have to stick with this. Anyway to improve it? Should i write both using() and also transaction.rollback?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all the individual db.SubmitChanges() make one call to db.SubmitChanges() right before the tx.Commit(). Let me know if this improves performance. It should prevent many roundtrips to the database and thus improve the overall performance.

Comment: Thanks, but i would need to submitChanges() so that i can get the id respectively to insert into another table..

Comment: Ah I see. In that case, there's no workaround. You have to make one insert at a time to generate the auto Ids. Are you doing this on a webserver which has direct connection to database? Or this is a desktop application talking to a remote database? 3-4 seconds sound quite high from a webserver talking to a database in the same network.